# How to integrate $\frac{1}{z}$ around square with vertices $(1,1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(-1,-1)$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

My attempt

$$\int_1^{-1} \frac{1}{x+i} \, dx+\int_1^{-1}
   \frac{i}{-1+i y} \, dy+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x-i} \, dx+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{i}{1+i y} \, dy=2\pi i$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. 
Since $\frac{1}{z}$ ist holomorphic except for the origin, you can change the path, as long you don't mix up with that singularity.

You have essantially a (counter-clockwise) circle around the origin, where a pole of order one is located.

Comment: Where do you mean "$\,\frac1z\;$ is holomorphic "...? And if it is holomorphic, what singularities are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, complex analysis is some years in the past. I meant "holomorphic everywhere but the origin", so the path can be changed. I'll edit the anwser.

Comment: Perhaps "analytic except at..." is more standard, but it doesn't really matters once you mention the singularities.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, but you don't have to calculate any integrals anyway. This is the core of the Residue theorem: an integral over a closed loop equals the sum of the encircled residues times $2\pi i$ (factors in front of poles of order $1$). In this case you have a single $1/z$ pole at the origin ($z=0$) with a prefactor of $1$, so the result is $2\pi i$ without looking.